# Deploying a smart contract by using a javascript file

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript, web3-providers

I want to deploy a contract using following javascript file, but I receive following error:

```
TypeError: web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\KX5710\Downloads\WeeChain\Test_2_Bala
nce\Deploy.js:25:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

=============

```
    const fs = require('fs');
////const solc = require('solc');
const Web3 = require('web3');

// Connect to local Ethereum node
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")); //18.221.104.179

// Contract object
////const contract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

// Deploy contract instance
const abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"En_value","type":"uint256"},{"name":"Pw_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"En_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"Pw_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_newProducer","type":"address"}],"name":"addNewProducer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_device","type":"address"}],"name":"getDeviceProducer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_device","type":"address"}],"name":"getDeviceConsumer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOfPw","outputs":[{"name":"Enbalance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getNumberOfProducers","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_device","type":"address"},{"name":"_consumer","type":"address"}],"name":"addDevice","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"producers","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"EntotalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"En_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"Pw_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"produceEnergyorPower","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOfEn","outputs":[{"name":"Enbalance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_producer","type":"address"}],"name":"isProducer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"PwtotalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_newProducer","type":"address"}],"name":"AddNewProducer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_producer","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_device","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_consumer","type":"address"}],"name":"AddNewDevice","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_producer","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"En_amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"Pw_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ProducerAddUnit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_device","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_producer","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_consumer","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"En_amount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"Pw_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ProducerChargeConsumer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_by","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"ChangementOwnership","type":"event"}]////JSON.parse(output.contracts[':MainToken'].interface);
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe', {
    from: web3.eth.coinbase,
    gas: 90000*2
}, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    // Log the tx, you can explore status with eth.getTransaction()
    console.log(res.transactionHash);

    // If we have an address property, the contract was deployed
    if (res.address) {
        console.log('Contract address: ' + res.address);
        // Let's test the deployed contract
        testContract(res.address);
    }
});
```

Comment: web3.eth.Contract should be web3.eth.contract

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion as kherwa said in the comment:

> web3.eth.Contract should be web3.eth.contract

Other options:

You might have an older version of web3js, is that possible? 
Also, have you added the compiled contract bytecode to the `new` call?

If that is the case do something closer to [this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contract-Tutorial#compiling-your-contract).

```
var _greeting = "Hello World!"
var greeterContract = web3.eth.contract(greeterCompiled.greeter.info.abiDefinition);

var greeter = greeterContract.new(_greeting,{from:web3.eth.accounts[0], data: greeterCompiled.greeter.code, gas: 1000000}, function(e, contract){
  if(!e) {

    if(!contract.address) {
      console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");

    } else {
      console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
      console.log(contract);
    }

  }
})
```